# VSTS - Build Wix MSI

Tags: c#, git, powershell, msbuild, wix

I am having trouble building my solution in VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services) which contains a Wix project.

I've tried using the Visual Studio Build process where I am pointing to my solution (using VS git repository)

When doing this it would firstly just freeze when it got to building the Wix project (it would build the custom action c# project and my test website project okay)

I tried using Nuget Restore so that VSTS would have the same version of Wix on the build server as is being used in the solution.

This would stop the freezing but would then show the following error

`TestWebsite\packages\WiX.3.10.3\tools\wix2010.targets(2481,7): Error MSB4064: The "SuppressPatchSequenceData" parameter is not supported by the "Light" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.`

Although in [Wix Light Task](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/task_reference/light.html) wiki there is an entry for SuppressPatchSequenceData

Looking up that error shows very little results so I found the following article

[Using PowerShell to create .msi packages](https://dondeetan.com/2015/07/24/creating-msi-packages-using-vso-build-services-a-simple-approach/)

I've followed the steps with a few minor adjustments, however, when I look in the outputted drop folder there is a

`TestInstaller.wixpdb`

but no

`TestInstaller.msi`

Which obviously is no use

Does anyone know the working solution to getting MSI packages built via VSTS specifically Wix projects

**EDIT**

I have since noticed (unsure if this is relevant) that my NuGet restore is not pulling anything for Test Installer. This is because the query was for ***.sln (WiX is .wixproj)

So I've added another NuGet restore step for .wixproj but I am getting the following error

`Cannot determine the packages folder to restore NuGet packages. Please specify either -PackagesDirectory or -SolutionDirectory.`

Comment: Did you try to build the solution on the build machine directly from command line using msbuild.exe?

Comment: @ArkadySitnitsky Sitnitsky When following the .MSI packages tutorial I linked. I ran the Powershell script directly on the server and it outputted the .MSI I want. I even took the parameters that were being passed during VSTS and pasted them into the script to ensure they were all okay and it still worked. I am currently updating the question now with extra information

Comment: What the time out that is set in your build definition? If you solution generates warnings so you may get a dead lock and the light will not finish. Try to remove the warnings or pass /p:RunWixToolsOutOfProc=true as msbuild argument.

Comment: @ArkadySitnitsky The time out is set to 60 mins and the build cancels itself once it's reached that time. I will try your suggestion tomorrow and get back to you. Thank you

Comment: Did my solution worked?